# In shell, is there a way to make a if statement that looks for anything but nothing, and how to parse arguments?

Tags: git, shell, if-statement, unix

I am trying to write a shell script that automates the git pushing process; add, commit and push. The full code is [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nswerhun/rice/master/scripts/pushall). I want it to work so when I pass the argument `-f`, I can then follow with my commit message. This is what I have so far:

```sh
fast() {
    git add -A
    echo ":: All changes tracked and staged."
    if [ "$2" = "" ]
    then 
        read -p "› Enter commit message: " commit
        echo
        echo "⇓ GIT OUTPUT ⇓"
        git commit -m "$commit"
        echo
    else
        echo "⇓ GIT OUTPUT ⇓"
        git commit -m "$*"
        echo
    fi 
    echo ":: Pushing to remote master."
    echo
    echo "⇓ GIT OUTPUT ⇓"
    git push -u origin master
    echo
    echo "Thanks for using pushall! Exiting..."
    exit
}
```

The problem I am having currently is that the `if` statement is not working as expected. No matter what I put after the `-f`, it always still asks me to enter a commit message. I was trying to make it so if I just ran `pushall -f` it would ask for a message, but if I ran `pushall -f foo` then it would commit with message "foo", and not ask.

Also, after I get the `if` statement working, how would I make the message only $3 and above, not $0, 1, and 2? I put $* just as a placeholder, but I have no idea how I would actually implement that. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Can you explain how the code in your post relates to the code you linked to? The function you post is not invoked, and the code you link to does not have this function. I'm guessing you're hitting what [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net) would automatically identify as [SC2120](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2120): trying to use a script's positional parameters in a function but failing to pass them along, but it's hard to say with the information you've provided

Comment: Ah yes, sorry, I forgot to update it, it should be the updated now, the function is toward the end.

Comment: how do you call the fast() function?

Comment: Why use `read` to get a one-line commit message instead of just running `git commit` without `-m`?

Comment: You'll want to use `"$@"`, not `"$*"`, to pass arguments *individually* to `git`.

Comment: Yusef - I call `fast` in another if-statement that looks for `-f` or `--fast` as the first argument.
chepner - If I just do `git commit`, I get an error telling me that it can't start vi, and to supply the message using `-m` or `-F`.

Comment: Please attach the entire script, I can guess your issue is in how you call the `fast` function.

Comment: Yusef - The entire script is attached at the top of the original post. Here is the link again: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nswerhun/rice/master/scripts/pushall

Comment: If you have to link to an external hosting service, your question isn't self-contained, but it should be.

Comment: There seems to be way too much unhelpful code here. Have your worked your way thru [Before asking about problematic code](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) section of `tags/bash/info`? (And also check out the **How to turn a bad script into a good question** section as well). Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The shell parameters in a shell function are the arguments *to that function*, not the arguments to the invoker but the ones supplied by it.  You've got

```
if [ "$1" = "-f" ] || [ "$1" = "--fast" ]
then
    fast
```

so your `fast` invocation supplies no arguments at all.

It's fallen out of favor because it's got that old-school git-r-dun flavor to it, but I think option processing is best done with `getopts` and `case`.

```
while getopts f:-: opt; do case $opt in
f) message="$OPTARG" ;;
-) case $OPTARG in 
   fast) message="${!OPTIND}"; ((++OPTIND));;
   esac ;;
esac; done; shift $((OPTIND-1))
```